# SWT on OS X: change application name

Tags: java, macos, swt

My SWT-based Java application shows `SWT` as application name in the application menu. I've tried changing it in Info.plist and using `Display.setAppName("myApp")` but it does not help. What else can I try?

BTW, I'm starting the application using a shell script which is located at `MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/MyApp`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Display.setAppName()` should work, at the condition that it is called *before* any `Display` instance is created (either by you or implicitly, e.g. if you call `Display.getDefault()`).

Comment: Thanks, the **before** was the key to the solution.

Answer (score -1):

Haven't tested it, but this [description](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/macosx/) should give an example...