# Execute something before static variables are initialized

Tags: java, macos, static, swt

I am developing a java application using SWT on mac.The application shows SWT as its title and i wanted to change it.I saw this [SWT on OS X: change application name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6690704/swt-on-os-x-change-application-name) question and wanted to use `Display.setAppName()`  but it should be used before i initialize any display as per the answer.Unfortunately i have declared my Display variable as static which will be initialized at the start of the app.How and where should i put this code so that it will be executed first before static variables are initialized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put them in the `static` blocks which get executed first .

```
static{
Display.setAppName()
}
```

See [In what order do static blocks and initialization blocks execute when using inheritance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19561332/what-is-order-of-execution-of-static-block-initialisatin-block-when-we-using-inh) to learn more

Comment: Worked!! Thanks.Will accept the answer in 11 minutes!